# AJAX Mouse Driven Signature Script (Sign and Save)

Tags: ajax, mouse, signature

I've found drawing program (point-based), I've found table-based version (with thousands of  elements), and I've found a solution which uses canvas, which apparently IE doesn't support.

There is a commercial script at realsignature.com which demonstrates what I'm looking to do. Be able to capture the users signature as a file.

Does anyone know of an open source or free solution?

Answer (score 0):

This brilliant fellow may have just what you need:

"A jQuery plugin for assisting in the creation of an HTML5 canvas based signature pad. Records the drawn signature in JSON for later regeneration."

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad

Comment: Hi, yup, I found that one too, but it uses 'canvas', which isn't IE compatible. Thanks for the effort.